# How to run husky pre-commit in child directory only

Tags: git, githooks, git-husky, husky

We have an enterprise application with a folder structure like the following:

```
/project
  .git
  /sub1
    ...Java project
  /sub2
    package.json
    ...Javascript Backbone project
  /sub3
    ...Java project
  /sub4
    ...Java project
  /sub5
    package.json
    ...Javascript React project
```

I currently have Husky set up both in sub2 and sub5 projects, which causes conflicts (requires an npm install whenever I switch projects).  Also, the Java developers are reporting that when they commit code in projects sub1, sub3 and sub4, the Husky git hooks are being executed.

Is it possible to only have the hooks run if you are IN a certain folder when you commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to only have the hooks run if you are IN a certain folder when you commit?

No, but the *hook itself* can determine *which directory it was in* when it was run.  This is not properly documented, but `GIT_PREFIX` is set in the environment before Git `chdir`-s to the `$GIT_WORK_TREE` or `$GIT_DIR` directory.  (This has been the case since Git version 1.7.8.)

Comment: can we get an example of how to use this?

Comment: @MauroColella: In shell code, use: `loc=${GIT_PREFIX:-.}` and then the directory you were in is in `$loc`. For instance, after `cd`-ing to the top level of the work-tree, `$loc` is just `.`, but after a subsequent `cd dir1/dir2`, `$loc` is `dir1/dir2`.

Answer (score 16):

While this question is a few years old. Hopefully someone will benefit from an updated answer provided by the folks from [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky).

**TL;DR**

See the new guidance [here](https://typicode.github.io/husky/guide.html#custom-directory).

**For those that w@ntz answ3rz n0wz!!**

New guidance that is provided in the [typicode/husky-init README.md](https://github.com/typicode/husky-init/commit/e1d4fe08d8b26060248fb961fee2b2f4c85e2288#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5R17) suggests the following when "*your `package.json` file and .git directory are not at the same level. For example, `project/.git` and `project/front/package.json`*"

You can change directory during prepare script and pass a subdirectory:

```json
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "cd .. && husky install front/.husky"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue. I fixed it by installing husky in the main directory.
my setup:

```
/project
    .git
    package.json
    /frontend
        package.json
    /frontend-admin
        package.json
```

In `/project/package.json`:

```
{
  "license": "MIT",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "frontend": "cd frontend && yarn lint"
    "frontend:admin": "cd frontend-admin && yarn lint",
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm-run-all frontend frontend:admin"
    }
  },
  // In the main folder you should install husky 
  // and npm-run-all to execute multiple commands
  "dependencies": {
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Your subdirectory should have a lint script to execute.
When one of the scripts crashes husky will give a report and abort immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue solved it by Installing and Running husky in /root directory.
(This is required as the husky needs to be in the same directory as .git folder.

```
npm install husky
npx husky install #use this command to create a .husky folder
```

Search for 'pre-commit' file

```
cd ./frontend && npm run lint && npm run build
cd ..
cd ./backend && npm run lint && npm run test
```

Note: Enter the same commands in order for you to execute each sub-directory/project
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

These projects usually come along with monorepos tools. In my case with lerna, a simple config can do what you need:

```
/root_workspace
    .git
    lerna.json
    package.json
    /sub-project-1
        package.json
    /sub-project-2
        package.json
```

- `~/root_workspace/.husky/precommit`: use proper lerna command for your project.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

# run script in a certain project
lerna exec npm run project_1_script --scope sub-project-1

# run script (one by one) in changed projects
lerna exec --concurrency 1 npm run some_script --since HEAD

# run script (one by one) in all projects
lerna exec --concurrency 1 npm run another_script
```

- `~/root_workspace/sub-project-1/package.json`

```json
// ...
"scripts": {
    "project_1_script": "echo \"project 1 script\"",
    "some_script": "echo \"script is triggered by changed project\"",
    "another_script": "echo \"script is triggered by all projects\""
}
```