# Git hooks in sub-directory

Tags: git, githooks

I have one repo that contains several React projects in different directories. For the structure

```
> Repo Root
  > .git
  > CRA Project1
  > CRA Project2
```

There are git hooks defined in the `.git` in the repo root for global things.
But I want to add hooks specifically for each project. Say, running custom linter with pre-commit in `CRA Project1` but not in `CRA Project2`.

How can I add hooks per project if global hook are already defined?

Comment: Do the different sub-projects have their own git repo to them?

Comment: No, they share same repo (the root repo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git doesn't have a notion of subprojects. From Git point of view the entire working tree with `.git/` repository at the top is just a single project with one set of hooks in `.git/hooks/`.

Said that, you could implement subproject hooks yourself with help from the global hooks. Every hook in `.git/hooks/` must determine if it's being run on global branches/commits/files or on subproject(s) and for subproject(s) it calls subproject hooks.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware to that. In my question I meant if there is a way to add register hooks in sub-directory. Similar concept of `.gitignore` file that can be defined in sub-directories and has the directory scope

Comment: "*if there is a way to add register hooks in sub-directory*" There is no until you implement it yourself. Something like [`husky`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53869155/7976758)